# Is this a proper use of static methods

Tags: c#, oop

I have read so many conflicting opinions on the use of static methods that my head hurts. Consider the following:

In most of my CRUD applications I use a SqlDataHandler class to handle the interactions with the database for a class (or in some cases group of classes). See below:

```
public abstract SqlDataHandler
{
    #region Properties
    protected static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    protected static DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand GetTableCommand)
    {
        ...
    }
    #endregion  
}

public AccountSqlDataHandler : SqlDataHandler
{
    #region Methods
    public static DataTable GetAccountHistory()
    {
        SqlCommand getAccountHistoryCommand;

        ...

        return AccountSqlDataHandler.GetDataTable(getAccountHistoryCommand);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Ctors
    static AccountSqlDataHandler()
    {
        AccountSqlDataHandler.ConnectionString = "Connection string for account database";
    }
    #endregion
}


public Account
{
    #region Properties
    public List<HistoryItem> AccountHistory
    {
        get
        {
            List<HistoryItem> accountHistory;

            accountHistory =         
                this.getItemsFromDataTable(AccountSqlDataHandler.GetAccountHistory());

        return accountHistory;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

As I see it if I use member methods, then either I have to create an AccountSqlDataHandler instance each time, or create an AccountSqlDataHandler member in the Account class. I don't see any advantage to doing this, but from what I'm reading there is an advantage. I would like to understand what it is before I blindly change my methodology.

Comment: this is subject to people's opinion, in the end what's best is going to be what works and makes sense to you (and your co-workers)

Comment: Instances make sense here because you can keep track of your connection/state and reuse it.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't be querying the database from a property.  Gets are assumed to have no side effects.  You should have a `GetAccountHistory` method instead.  However, it also sounds like `Account` is a data object, which has no business querying a database.

Comment: @cadrell0 Why does a data object have no business querying a database?

Comment: Single Responsibility and Separation of Concerns.  A data object is concerned with holding data.  Typically a repository class is used to query the database and create data objects.  In this case,  you can have instance members on your SqlDataHandler class, but only one instance of it on in an AccountsRepository.

Comment: @cadrell0 I think what you are talking about is what I need to learn but I don't really understand what you are describing. Do you know of an article, etc where I can learn the structure you're talking about with a bit of explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  In fact, there will be a nice bug for you when you add and use a second handler.

Try this code out (hopefully you'll notice the similarity with your `ConnectionString` property):

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bravo = new Bravo();
        var charlie = new Charlie();

        Console.WriteLine(bravo.GetValue());
        Console.WriteLine(charlie.GetValue());

        Bravo.EchoValue();
        Charlie.EchoValue();
    }
}

public abstract class Alpha
{
    protected static string Value { get; set; }

    public abstract string GetValue();
}

public class Bravo : Alpha
{
    static Bravo()
    {
        Value = "bravo";
    }

    public override string GetValue()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public static void EchoValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Value);
    }
}

public class Charlie : Alpha
{
    static Charlie()
    {
        Value = "charlie";
    }

    public override string GetValue()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public static void EchoValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
charlie
charlie
charlie
charlie
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

`ConnectionString` is effectively shared state and modifying it in static constructors means that the last static constructor call will set the state for the entire application (until something sets it to what it wants it to be but then this *must* be the rule and then the static constructors are pointless).  This will inevitably lead to the *why is my accounts query hitting the orders database?* problems (because a developer didn't explicitly set the connection string prior to every usage) as well as kill any chance at this application working in a multi-database context.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it's not quite what i'm asking. The GetValue method is a member method. You'll note that GetAccountHistory is also static. I never declare an instance of the AccountSqlDataHandler, so I don't run into this specific bug.

Comment: @jemartin80: See the static `EchoValue` methods...  You will have the problem for both static and instance methods that use `ConnectionString`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I would upvote you but I don't have enough rep points. There is a bug intrinsic to the model I have suggested, and this points it out.

Answer (score 3):

A good rule of thumb is to use a static method if the method is not dependent on a specific instance.  I.E.

```
public static int Add (x, y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

And you should use instance methods if you do depend on the instance.

```
public int Add(x)
{  
    return this.y + x;
}
```

---

Now your specific issue is Maybe you connect to multiple databases, or you have multiple connection strings.

If you do, than it makes perfect sense to instantiate your sql data handlers.  but if you don't than there's not much need.

Comment: But OP has made everything in the `SqlDataHandler` class static, so none of it depends on the instance.

Comment: @cadrell0: The point is that if requirements change in the future and, for example, multiple `ConnectionString`s are needed then it will be hard to move away from the static implementation. If no external information is needed, static methods are fine. But many times static variables really should be instance variables.

Comment: @Cemafor All I was trying to point out was the Sam's rule of "if it only uses static members, make it static" doesn't give any guidance when everything has been forced to static.  OP needs a better understanding of when and when not to use static before this rule will apply.

Comment: @cadrell0 Exactly, you understand what I'm trying to get at. But if there was a different connection string for the account object, then I would just change the static ctor. If it's for a different type of object I would create a different sub-class of SqlDataHandler, which is what I would do if I had instance methods as well to avoid having hundreds of loosely related methods in one class. It easier to use AccountSqlDataHandler, SalesSqlDataHandler, WidgetsSqldDataHandler, than to look through one god-class containing 100s of calls to different schemas or databases.

Comment: @cadrell0 I forgot the question part, Why is what I said above not the best way?

Answer (score 1):

In general `static` should be something when that behavior logically belongs to a `class` or `type` instead of its instances and static data when that data is shared among all instances.
In your case it looks like you want a `Singleton` for each database. Take a look at that pattern. Many times I've seen singleton being implemented as static classes/methods which is not correct.

Another thing in .NET, there is a general guideline that static methods are (should be) thread safe but instance methods are not. You have to take care of this guideline when implementing static methods.

Comment: That's interesting, thank you. Why is my implimentation not correct as opposed to the Singleton?

Comment: @jemartin80: Singleton have advantage over static like they can implement interface and object can be passed to method which expect interface or base class. Singletons just fit better into OOP that way.